# In-app Billing GoogleTV

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-tv, sony

I try to make a GoogleTV Version of our existing App with In-app Billing. Everything works fine on Tablets and Phones, but I have a Problem to get it running on Google TV. The App get stuck in the Billing process.

I just tried to setup the dungeon example from Google to test basic functionality. It works on Phones and Tablets, but I get the following Message on the GTV-Device:

> ### Can't make purchases
>
> The Market billing service is not available at this time. You can continue to use this app but you won't be able to make purchases.

I rebooted the Device and made a factory reset, but no changes.

Now my questions.

Does the Sony NSZ-GS7 support In-app billing? What's going wrong?

**Device:** Sony NSZ-GS7
| **OS:** Android 3.2
| **Google Play:** 1.2.0
| **MyApps:** 5.0.12

**Update:**

The Guide from Gaunt Face helped me. The Dungeon Example starts now. But if I make a purchase, the in-app Billing gets stuck at "Authorizing purchase..." after 30 sec I get "Application My Apps (in process com.android.vending) is not responding".

This is the same problem I get with my App.

Is it possible there's still a bug with Sony NSZ-GS7?

Answer (score 3):

Google TV does support in-app billing, but it doesn't support subscription billing.

Please see here for a guide on getting the demo to work: http://www.gauntface.co.uk/blog/2012/08/15/google-tv-in-app-billing/

Subscription billing will work once the native Google Play store is installed on GTV's which should be rolling out soon: http://googletv.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/google-play-movies-tv-shows-and-music.html

Comment: Your Guide helped me. The Dungeon Example starts now. But if I make a purchase, the in-app Billing gets stuck at "Authorizing purchase..." after 30 sec I get "Application My Apps (in process com.android.vending) is not responding". This is the same problem I have with my App.

Comment: unfortunately there are no errors in logcat: 10-09 12:13:50.561: D/Dungeons(603): buying: android.test.purchased sku: android.test.purchased
10-09 12:13:50.571: D/BillingService(603): RequestPurchase
10-09 12:13:50.701: D/BillingService(603): request id: 8371378094754859419
10-09 12:13:50.701: D/BillingService(603): RequestPurchase
10-09 12:13:50.721: D/BillingService(603): request id: 4267694279871543983

Comment: I did have to leave the application for a day and come back to it before the play store started to work with the items. I know its a poor answer, but some people developing mobile and tablet apps experienced the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`Does the Sony NSZ-GS7 support In-app billing?` NO

"If your device is running Android 3.0, in-app billing requires version 5.0.12 (or higher)"

For more [read.](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

Comment: The Device is running Android 3.2 and MyApps 5.0.12